# using imgs in multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to load an image from a multidimensional array however I can't seem to get the images to display. They only show as the text.

```
function cartoonsRndm(x) {
    var cartoon = new Array();
    cartoon[0] = {
        person: "Trixie",
        show: "my little pony",
        img: "img/trixie.jpg"
    };
    cartoon[1] = {
        person: "Sanic",
        show: "Sanic the hagehug",
        img: "img/sanic.png"
    };
    cartoon[2] = {
        person: "megaman",
        show: "blue bomber",
        img: "img/man.jpg"
    };
    var hero = cartoon[x]["person"] + " " + cartoon[x]["show"] + " " + cartoon[x][src = "img"]
    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = hero
}
```

Comment: You haven't put `<img>` in the HTML you're creating.

Comment: Who is `Sanic the Hagehug`? Missed that one in my youth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are concatenating a string with `src` value. You need to construct `<img>` HTML tag:

```
var hero = cartoon[x].person + " " + cartoon[x].show + " <img src='" + cartoon[x].img + "'>";
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = hero;
```

Also note that `cartoon[x]["person"]` is equivalent to `cartoon[x].person` but shorter.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = '<img src="'+cartoon[0]['img']+'">';
```